# Android ndk-build command returning 'target pattern contains no '%'

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, adt

I've seen other questions like this, but they don't seem to solve my problem. I am trying to build a C++/Android project on Windows for the first time, and have a few questions:

1) Android NDK docs said cygwin is required, some people on internet say it isn't. I have tried both. But I'm getting many errors in building our project using ndk-build on both cmd.exe and cygwin window. On cygwin it says

```
 *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
```

I searched that there might be some windows style path there in the make files. Someone said use : `$(shell cygpath -u $(path))` instead of `$(path)` ... It's not helping.

2) Since it's a big project, I wanted to check which all are the places where it's taking a windows style path. But even the simple @echo commands for echoing their values is not working.

```
@echo $(path)
```

Some on the internet said we can use this style:

```
.PHONY: print_vals
print_vals:
<tab>@echo $(path)
```

but that is not working either. Android NDK development on Windows is difficult :(.

Answer (score 1):

First, Cygwin is not required to run ndk-build on Windows, only to run ndk-gdb, and there is also a python version (ndk-gdb.py) that doesn't require Cygwin anyway.

Second, there must be something weird in your Android.mk file(s). If you don't know how GNU Make works, you should really restrict yourselves to the features described by the NDK documentation (e.g. $NDK/docs/ANDROID-MK.html and $NDK/docs/HOWTO.html)

It's hard to tell exactly why you're seeing this message, but it's very likely because you're using absolute Windows file paths in direct target definitions.

Finally, you cannot use echo to debug Makefiles, use `$(info path=$(path))` instead.